# Where in Android should I store photos that need to be uploaded to a server?

Tags: android, filesystems, storage

These photos should not go into the user's gallery. The user will be taking one or more photos (maybe dozens), which need to be processed and then uploaded to a server in the background. I do not want to use `Activity.getCacheDir()` because the photos might be deleted before they are uploaded. After the photos are successfully uploaded, they will be deleted.

Where can I put these photos for semi-permanent storage? Do I just make my own directory, or is there a method I can call to get an appropriate directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I just make my own directory, or is there a method I can call to get an appropriate directory?

Use `getFilesDir()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`, or some subdirectory that you create off of there.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar method for getting the external device storage directory for my app? Is `getObbDir()` the right one?

Comment: Is there a limit of how much space I can take with my images?

Comment: @BLuFeNiX: "Is there a similar method for getting the external device storage directory for my app?" -- `getExternalFilesDir()`. But that will get your files indexed by the `MediaStore` if they hang around long enough to get picked up by the scanner.

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec: On Android 3.0+ devices, you are limited only by the amount of available space on the device. That being said, please do not irritate the user.